# Google-talkplugin not working in Ubuntu 12.04 64bit

Tags: 12.04, google-talk

Google-talkplugin is not working for me on Ubuntu 12.04 (Precise) 64-bit, I have reinstalled the system many times to get it to work but still it doesn't.

The problem is not with AppArmor as I have checked it with `strace firefox`.

Anyone else has it? Do you have any ideas & workarounds? What can I do to help fix it as I couldn't find a Google bug tracker for the plugin?

Comment: If it makes you feel better, google-talk has never ever worked for me. If fact, it's unclear, why would Google use flash at all, as that technology is on the way out.

Comment: Google-talk was the only nicely working VoIP except Skype before I switched to Precise.

Comment: I have installed Chrome, Linphone from PPA and checked lots of logs and... now Firefox is working badly (I don't know why, it's saying that something disturbs it) but the plugin is working. Mysterious

Comment: I just installed it on my 64-bit Precise and it is working fine without installing any of the above. I'm using it through Chromium.

Answer (score 2):

It works for me in Chrome but I had to enable all plugins: `Settings->Privacy->Content Settings->Plugins->Run` Automatically. I set this when I want to make a call, then set to to "**Click To Play**" when browsing the web.

I have not tried Firefox so I can't help you there.

Comment: This did not work for me, even when "Run automatically" was set.

Answer (score 1):

This used to work in Chromium, but I was never able to get it to work in Chromium after I upgraded to 12.10.  However, when I [installed Chrome](https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/) it works.  I'm not sure why.

You can tell the difference between Chrome and Chromium because of the application icons.  Chrome is in colour and Chromium is all shades of blue.

### Chromium vs Chrome

[image: Chromium on Left, Chrome on Right]

---

Comment: Installing Chrome fixes the issue for me ! Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the google talk plugin is flash based, you may be having problems with the new version of flash.

Not guaranteed to fix your problem, but try disabling the latest version of flash (will default to 11.2 instead).

- Type `about:plugins` in the url bar
- Click details
- Disable Flash

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `cheese` if it is instaled. Google-talkplugin should work fine after that.

Comment: I tried disabling 'cheese', and Chromium still set me to the wizard to install the Google talk plugin, even though it was already installed.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you enable pop-ups, since the video call appears in a pop-up window.

Settings->Privacy->Content Settings->Pop-ups->Allow all sites to show pop-ups.